# License for international hunters in Canada

Tags: hunting, canada

How do hunting licenses work when travelling abroad for hunting? It's not a case of re-locating to a new country, just spending some time there. Is there an international recognition of a national license? Or are international licenses just the privilege of the extremely wealthy travelling to the extremely poor regions (in exotic places like Botswana)?

I have interest in how a international group of people (mainly from the UK) could go on a hunting holiday in Canada.

Comment: You should try making your question more specific, someone might be able to help you find a license for the region you're traveling to. There is no such 'international hunting license.' Poorer regions simply don't have the resources to effectively enforce hunting regulations.

Comment: What type of game are you thinking of hunting? I have my hunting licence and live in Canada. I know a lot of Americans do hunt for larger game in my province. I am not sure, but have a strong feeling that the answer to your question will vary from country to country. If you are hunting larger game, most provinces hold a lottery here in Canada for the licences to hunt certain large game each season.

Comment: Nope, no caribou or the like. It would be more like wild boars.

Comment: I'm interested in this too, but travelling from the US - WA state to be precise, so just up and over the border.

Comment: be prepared to spend a lot of money - non-resident alien costs for a specific tag are typically an order of magnitude greater than for residents and most if not all provinces / territories will require you to be with a registered guide and they charge plenty $$$

Answer (score 3):

In Canada, you will need a hunting license depending on the province (or territory) and type of game you wish to hunt. Typically, a safety course is also required.

For example, moose requires applying for a draw which is valid for a certain zone as determined by the department of natural resources.

- [Moose Hunting British-Columbia](http://www.env.gov.bc.ca/fw/wildlife/hunting/non_resident/)
- [Moose Hunting New-Brunswick](http://www2.gnb.ca/content/gnb/en/services/services_renderer.200853.moose_hunting_licence_.html)